# How to reset class variables without reseting the current instance ones

Tags: php, class, methods

I was unable to find a similar question on Stackoverflow, although I am sure someone has probably asked this before.

I have a class with methods that may be called several times per page. Each time the method is called I need to make sure the public variables are reset to their defaults, **UNLESS** they have been set before calling the method.

**This cannot be achieved using a simple if condition because there is no way to tell whether the value has been set or is still set from the last method call**

I cannot think of a way to achieve this because I cannot call my __construct method (which sets all the default values), as this would overwrite the parsed values. However, I need to reset them to prevent values from the last method call from being parsed.

**The obvious answer is to give different names to the public variables and the return variables. I will do this if there is no other option but I like to keep the number of variables to a minimum**

It is very hard to explain this in writing so I will update this question with an example of what I mean in code.

**UPDATE**

An example of where a problem may occur:

```
<?php

class test{
    public $return_array;
    public $return_string;
    public $return_bool;

    function __construct(){

        // Set the default values
        $this->return_array = false;
        $this->return_string = false;
        $this->return_bool = false; 

    }

    public function method(){
        // ... do something
        $array = array('test');
        $string = 'test';
        $bool = true;

        // Only return variables if asked to
        $this->return_array = $this->return_array ? $array : NULL;
        $this->return_string = $this->return_string ? $string : NULL;
        $this->return_bool = $this->return_bool ? $bool : NULL;
        return;
    }
}

// Initiate the class
$test = new test;

// Call the method the first time with one parameter set
$test->return_array = true;
$test->method();

// Print the result
print_r($test->return_array);

// MOST OBVIOUS ANSWER WOULD BE TO RESET VARIABLES HERE LIKE SO
$test->reset(); // HOWEVER, I DO NOT WANT TO HAVE TO CALL THIS EACH TIME I CALL THE METHOD, HERE LIES MY PROBLEM!

// Call the method again with different parameters
$test->return_string = true;
$test->return_bool = true;
$test->method();

// Print the result
echo $test->return_array;
echo $test->return_bool;

/* The problem lies in the second call of the method because $test->return_array has not been reset to its default value. However, there is no way to reset it without affecting the other variables. */

?>
```

**This is basically a very long winded way of asking whether it is possible to reset a classes variables to their default values, whilst ignoring the ones that have been parsed to the method being called**

Comment: It's not clear what your concept of "parsed" means. -- And if it's ambigious if a method should return values or set properties, then make it two methods. One for the functionality, and a second that optionally overwrites the properties.

Comment: I always thought that passing values to a function was known as parsing, obviously not. Making it two methods will not sort this issue because the variables will still be declared and not reset

Comment: You should definitely give a real example. Sounds like you are looking for the right solution to the wrong problem.

Comment: I cannot give a real example as I haven't written it yet. The best way I can describe this is with the code I have written. The same method is called twice, with different variables passed to it. However, on the second call to the method, the initial $test->return_array, is still set from the previous one. This needs to be reset without reseting the newly declared variables. See my edit on the code part in a min

Comment: This is probably another dumb question: but why don't you use `->method($parameters,...)` for that? It seems the setting should only apply once. Or why not let the method return all three result thingys at once?

Comment: The method parameters is definitely a possibility. It hadn't crossed my mind to use them in this case. I have considered the second option because that would mean that I could initialise a reset at the end of each method call and this would not interfere. I will probably end up going for the latter as I can just return my results in an associative array. The reason for my question was purely because I wanted to know whether it was a common problem and there was a predefined workaround. The obviously isn't but this answer will do just fine. Thanks very much

Comment: can't you just make a custom function that only changes non-default values

Comment: Not possible because there is no way of telling whether or not they are non-default as it could be a parameter declared for the last method called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this but they all bottle down to the same solution. Calling a function after each method that resets the variables within the class. Best way to do this is at the end of each method before the data is returned.